# How to launch aicas license provider ? and call files with jamaicaVM?

Tags: java, eclipse, real-time, rtsj, jamaicavm

I am building a real time program with RTSJ and having trouble running my code with jamaicaVM in the terminal. I have written my code in eclipse and have installed the jamaicavm tools into my eclipse. It is currently in the already installed software.

Now I want to call jamaicavm filename and run my file but I am having trouble launching the aicas license provider, so that I can run the file. Any thoughts?

my update-site-jamaica6 folder is in my java project's folder.

Answer (score 1):

One way to launch your application from terminal is if you build it.

To build an application in Eclipse, you have to make a build file and run it.

Go File -> New -> Other, Jamaica -> Jamaica Buildfile, give your main class and open the build file. On the overview tab you will find a button build which will compile your code into an executable and will be placed at your project's folder.

Note that some parameters are set to 0, ie memory areas.